# I want to make the text below the CSS shape be on top

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I already tried z-index. I think it has something to do with the pseudo classes, but I don't know what it is, exactly... I'm a newbie so I can only do HTML and CSS for now, I don't know any JS. Thank you! :)

```css
.h1bcg {
  margin-top: 180px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 666px;
}

.h1bcg:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  background: rgba(88, 255, 171, 0.7);
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  box-shadow:  0.1rem 0.6rem 9px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.h1bcg:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: rgba(88, 255, 171, 0.7);
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  box-shadow:  0.1rem 0.6rem 9px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
      <div class="h1bcg:before h1bcg:after ">
         <h1 class="text-center h1bcg"> Lorem              ipsum dolor sit amet. </h1>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo classes and z-index is correct.

Position the pseudo-classes below the element by giving it a negative z-index.

Also note: Pseudo classes (the `:before` and `:after` styling rules) are applied to the element containing the original class (`.h1bcg`) appropriately.  You don't have to specify these classes in your HTML for them to take effect.

```css
.h1bcg {
  margin-top: 180px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 666px;
}

.h1bcg:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  background: rgba(88, 255, 171, 0.7);
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  box-shadow:  0.1rem 0.6rem 9px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.h1bcg:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: rgba(88, 255, 171, 0.7);
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  box-shadow:  0.1rem 0.6rem 9px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="text-center h1bcg"> Lorem              ipsum dolor sit amet. </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know that! Thank you! I'm starting to use pseudo classes so I was a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

I think u are looking for the below result.

For that I've added a neganitve `z-index` to both psuedo classes (`.h1bcg:after` and `.h1bcg:before`).

Hope it helps.

```css
.h1bcg {
  margin-top: 180px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 666px;
}

.h1bcg:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  background: rgba(88, 255, 171, 0.7);
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  box-shadow:  0.1rem 0.6rem 9px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  z-index:-1;
}

.h1bcg:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: rgba(88, 255, 171, 0.7);
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  box-shadow:  0.1rem 0.6rem 9px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="h1bcg:before h1bcg:after ">
  <h1 class="text-center h1bcg"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow... I feel so silly now. I had tried negative z-index values and didn't work, but now it did perfectly. I was definitely doing something wrong, thank you so much!